# How to open access to a image for javascript in a Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a problem. My javascript code:

```
function fromPinkToBlue(){
    document.querySelector('#img').src = '../static/images/x2coin.png'
    document.querySelector('#img').setAttribute('style', 'width: 300px; height: 300px')
}
```

In this code, I change the pictures by changing the path to the file, but here's the problem. In order for the server to process this picture, you need to somehow register the second picture in the Thymeleaf
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/conflip.css" th:href="@{/css/conflip.css}">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
          xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JADEN</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../static/circle-16.ico" th:href="@{/circle-16.ico}"  type="image/x-icon">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title>Jaden</title>

</head>



    <body>


<a href="javascript:show_hide('block')"><img id="img"  src="../static/images/x1coin.png" th:src="@{/images/x1coin.png}" class="image"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></img></a>

        <br>
        <br><input type="submit" id="flipX" value="Flip!">

    </body>


<script type="module" src="../static/js/flipper.js" th:src="@{/js/flipper.js}"></script>
</html>
```

The server sees the first picture, because I registered the location in the time-leaf. How to register this for the second one, so that the javascript can change the path? Otherwise, it is not possible to implement the substitution of images :(

Of course, it is impossible to register two time-lif paths. Nothing else comes to mind

Comment: Maybe you can load the two images and just replace the pictures using a "click" event for example ?

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript code, in my case, the path had to be written like this: images/x2coin.png